# How to check type, anonimty and response time of a Proxy server using Java

Tags: java, http, proxy, socks

I need some help here.

I'll try to explain my problem.
I have a list of Proxy servers and I want to check if they works, what type of proxy server is (HTTP/HTTPS or SOCKS), the anonimity level (Transparent, Anonymous, Elite) and, of course,the response time. My goal is to do a some sort of proxy checker.

But one problem at time.

At the moment my code is the following (Proxy is a custom Object, not java.net.Proxy). I do this iterating the ObservableList containing the Proxy servers:

```
// Checks if it works
if (isReachable(ip, port, 10000)) {

    // Sets proxy status to "Working"
    proxy.setStatus("Working");

    // checkType(ip, port);
    // checkAnonimty(ip, port);
    // checkResponseTime(ip, port);

} else {

    // Sets speed to default (0) and sets proxy to "Dead" status
    proxy.setSpeed(new Long(0));
    proxy.setStatus("Dead");

}
```

Now, I tried different ways to check type, anonimity and response time, but nothing worked.

For the "checkType" function I thought to check the connection for every proxy type (DIRECT, HTTP, SOCK), then return the type that worked. I tried this solution but all I got are "connections reset" errors.

For the "checkAnonimity" function I don't even know where to start. Any help and suggestion would be awesome. I know using PHP would be easy, but what if I want to use Java?

For the last function, "checkResponseTime", I thought to do a regualar connection to some site after I have all Proxy information and count the time to get a response. So this is pretty simple, I think.

Anyone can give me some help and suggestions?
I tried to do this on my server using PHP, but my free hosting seems to use a "Firendly error page" for non existent hosts, so it's hard to know if the proxy host is reachable or not.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi have you figured it out , I ran into same problem